# ISEXP : fatal error -6017: Internal build error

Tags: installshield, visual-foxpro, installshield-express

When I try to build my InstallShield package I get:

> Searching project for extract-at-build components...
>
> Extracting COM data from 2 component(s)
>
> ISEXP : fatal error -6017: Internal build
>
> error Express\SingleImage - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

I'm using: InstallShield Express Visual FoxPro Limited Edition, Version 5.0.

Where do I even start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run InstallShield Express as an **Administrator**

Comment: Haven't used Express, I was not aware that it could run without admin rights at all.

Comment: Windows 11 (dec 2021), ok as admin.